# Searching for a string in a list with a regular expression

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to install VirtualBox with the following task:

```
- name: Install VirtualBox RPM from "{{ virtualbox_url }}"
  dnf:
    name: "{{ virtualbox_url }}"
    state: present
  when: "'VirtualBox-6.0' not in ansible_facts.packages"
  tags: vagrant
```

This works but I would like to change my when: clause to use 'VirtualBox" without the version. After conducting a a couple of tests it looks like the string in the when: clause needs to match exactly:

```
>>> list = ["Foo-6.0"]
>>> if "Foo" in list:
...    print("Yay")
...

>>> if "Foo-6.0" in list:
...    print("Yay")
...
Yay
```

Does Ansible have a way to match the list members against a regular expression? Something like the following?:

```
import re
[f for f in ansible_facts.packages if re.search("VirtualBox",f)]
```

I read through the filters and test documentation and I can't seem to find a recipe to do this. This seems like a common issue so I must be searching for the wrong thing (was searching for "ansible match string in list with regex"). If anyone has a suggestion or a link with a recipe for doing this I would be super appreciative if you could share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in` operator can be used against list or strings

The first form:

```
'string' in ['elem1', 'elem2']
```

will match if one element of the list is exactly `string`

The second form:

```
'substring' in 'string'
```

will match if `substring` is contained somewhere in `string`

An easy way in your case to go around the problem with your list of packages is to search for your substring in the entire concatenated list:

```
when: "'VirtualBox' not in ansible_facts.packages | join"
```

This technique can also be used with regular expressions if needed...

```
when: ansible_facts.packages | join is match('.*VirtualBox.*')
```

... or with the `search` test

```
when: ansible_facts.packages | join is search('VirtualBox')
```